# javascript/css style doesn't implement to all buttons

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to customize a list. My code:

```
<script>
for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    $("button").css({
        'background-color': '#CAC9DB',
        'width': '40px',
        'height': '40px',
        'font-size': '24px',
        'font-weight': 'bold'
    });
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(n);
    node.appendChild(btn);
    btn.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(node);
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the css style for buttons is implemented only for the first two buttons and not for the last. Why isn't the last button formatted according to css style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you go around the loop you:

1. Create a button
2. Change the style of all the buttons in the DOM
3. Add the button created in step 1 to the DOM

You don't restyle all the buttons after you've put the last one in the DOM.

Change `$("button").css({` to `$(btn).css({` to restyle the button you've just created (before you add it to the DOM).

---

Inline style generally isn't a good idea, and there is nothing dynamic about the rules you are applying. You would probably be better off just defining the styles for `button` in a CSS file (or for `button.something` with `$(btn).addClass('something')` if globally styled buttons aren't appropriate for your site).

Comment: `Change $("button").css({ to $(btn).css({ to restyle the button you've just created (before you add it to the DOM).` Why? Put the `$.css()` after `for` loop

Comment: @Tushar — It guarantees there won't be a FOUC and changing all the buttons globally smells like something that will trip people up the future if differently styled buttons are ever added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

As you're applying the styles to all the `button` elements, I'd recommend you to use CSS rules for this.

```
button {
    background-color: #CAC9DB;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

If you want to style only newly created `button`s, then add a class to the buttons.

Javascript:

```
button.className = 'myButton';
```

CSS:

```
button.myButton {
    background-color: #CAC9DB;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style only the actual button rather than all `buttons` using jQuery:

```
for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    $(btn).css({
        'background-color': '#CAC9DB',
        'width': '40px',
        'height': '40px',
        'font-size': '24px',
        'font-weight': 'bold'
    });
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(n);
    node.appendChild(btn);
    btn.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(node);
}
```

ex. http://jsfiddle.net/41Lk5xeo/

Or better yet add them all and then style at the end:

```
for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(n);
    node.appendChild(btn);
    btn.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(node);
}

$('button').css({
    'background-color': '#CAC9DB',
    'width': '40px',
    'height': '40px',
    'font-size': '24px',
    'font-weight': 'bold'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5m0ehe6/

Answer (score -1):

Write css style code after `document.getElementById('list').appendChild(node);`.